# Why is 100% height adding a vertical scrollbar?

Tags: html, css

I've looked at many answers to this question but none of them seem to solve my issue. I have a div set to 100% height but it adds a vertical scrollbar to my site. Why is 100% height adding a vertical scrollbar? How can I remove it and still have it be 100% height?

**Solutions recommended:**

- 100% height on html & body
- overflow: hidden;
- `* {overflow:hidden;}`

*None of these solve my issue*

***Example of my issue (div three adds a scrollbar if height is set to 100%)***

https://jsfiddle.net/wqy0bx5b/

**Code:**

HTML//

```
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="three">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
<div class="four">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

CSS//

```
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.one {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #c4c9d4;
}
.two{
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #a7aebe;
}
.three{
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  background-color: #8a93a8;
}
.four{
  width: 80%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #576075;
}
```

Comment: Because `.three` has a height of 100% also, this is being added to the 130px of `.one` & `.two`. - https://jsfiddle.net/wqy0bx5b/1/

Comment: I really don't see what your issue is..? 50px + 80px + 100% of the container (this being body) - is 100%+130px. The example you provided is doing exactly what you told it to.

Comment: Thank you! @Paulie_D That's a solution I've never seen be used. Never used calc, thanks.

Comment: If you want more flexibility with your layout, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/90178/5743988). In particular, a flexbox or CSS table layout may work for you.

Answer (score 0):

[**Paulie_D**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2802040/paulie-d) solved my issue.

Div three needed:

```
height: calc(100% - 130px);
```

I didn't realize the height of div 1 & 2 were already being added to the 100% height of div 3. Haven't heard of calc till now, thanks Paul.